# How to implement a servlet/applet combination with two different functions?

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, spring-mvc, applet

I've been tasked with creating a Java web application that consists of two pages, a "Draw" page and an "Evaluate" page. I'll be developing in Eclipse.

The "Draw" page will facilitate the following process:

- Take user input from a form
- Using a Servlet, build a model in the background
- Send the model to an Applet (probably via JSON) on the client-side to be rendered visually

The "Evaluate" page will:

- Take user input from a similar form to build a similar object (same class) using a Servlet
- Run a the model through an algorithm on the Servlet, and display the results on screen.

The pages can be relatively independent.

My question is, exactly how should I go about implementing this combination?

I'm familiar with Servlet development and the Spring MVC/Webflow framework, but in no way an expert. However, I'm guessing Spring would be overkill for this simple application, and I've never implemented a Servlet that has more than one major function.

Should I make an HttpServlet that just has conditional logic in the doGet/doPost methods, and performs an operation based on the request's URL?

Should I make two separate Servlets?

If so, would I make two separate projects in Eclipse, or just one project with two Servlets registered in web.xml? Should I do something totally different?

I'm not looking for code, but just would like to have a stronger understanding of how to approach this type of application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to provide an opposing view to that of Dmitri's. I think its great for people to know how to write plain servlets but when it comes to writing code for a business I think you'd be better off using Spring MCV. The main reasons are:

- you already have experience with Spring MVC, so no learning curve
- although the requirements seem straight forward, my experience is that web projects like this quickly grow way beyond their initial specs, at which point you'll be wishing you'd used Spring MVC
- You will have to code and maintain the features in a servlet which are normally handled by Spring MVC - I love the saying: they have solved problems that you haven't even thought about yet.
- every line of code you write has the potential to be buggy, by reducing the amount of code you write you reduce the risk of bugs
- Spring MVC is designed in a such a way that you can use as little or as much of the features that you like/need. With annotations, you can get a simple app up and running with a surprising small number of lines of code/xml
- testing is much easier with Spring MVC
- Spring MVC follows a convention that other programmers already know. If you leave your job, then someone can pick it up very quickly. OTOH if you code a simple servlet, you could do it a number of different ways that could make it harder to maintain for someone else
- with modern hardware/OS, the extra memory/overheads that adding Spring MVC adds to you project is negligible - we no longer run our servers with 128KB of memory but some people still have a mindset that we do. If in doubt benchmark it, don't early optimise!

Answer (score 1):

Spring (or any other MVC) framework is definitely overkill for this, servlets will do just fine.

Make sure all of your actual logic is in a separate class, all your servlets should do is apply whatever processing needs to be done to read the user input, and call the appropriate methods on your service class. Basically keep the web-specific parts minimal.

Whether it's two separate servlets or one that switches on the request path doesn't really matter.  I'd use two separate ones, since mapping requests to methods is pretty much what servlets are designed to do.

You do not need separate projects in Eclipse, just define the servlets in web.xml (or with annotations if on Servlet 3.0).

It sounds like you're on the right track.